# get value of slider in another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have a slider in one html page, and I want to access the value of the slider in another page.

Here's the slider, in a page called "settings.html":

```
<div class="widget uib_w_4 no_wrap no_swipe-x with-label d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/slider" data-ver="0" id="sliderAlliteration">
                <label class="narrow-control label-top-left" for="sliderAlliteration">Alliteration</label>
                <div class="wide-control">
                  <input type="range" value="10" min="0" max="10" step="1">
                </div>
              </div>
```

So the `id` of the slider is `"sliderAlliteration"`, and I have attempted to access the value of this slider in a javascript script file:

```
var alliterationLevel = $("#sliderAlliteration").val();
```

However, `alliterationLevel` comes up as `undefined`. How can I access the slider's value?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
alliterationLevel = $("#sliderAlliteration div input").val();
```

To get the **input** value, since **#sliderAlliteration** is a div and has no value.

Comment: try it again, remove the _var_ and add _div_ after **#sliderAlliteration**